# Remove all text after last occurrence of a substring in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I have a MySQL table with School Data that looks like this:

```
| Associated Hebrew Schools of Toronto - Central Administration - North York |
| SIr Allen McNab                                                            |
| West Ridge                                                                 |
| CNC                                                                        |
| krss                                                                       |
| College of new Caledonia                                                   |
| yarmishl1                                                                  |
| college of new calendonia                                                  |
| ben                                                                        |
| john mcginnis                                                              |
| Thousand Islands Secondary School - Brockville                             |
| École élémentaire Richardson Elementary - Delta                            |
| Centre of Excellence for Entrepreneurship                                  |
| St. Gabriel Cyber School - Red Deer                                        |
| Highwood School - Calgary                                                  |
| Janus Academy - Calgary
```

Many Schools have City names at the end e.g. `Highwood School - Calgary` and many schools
don't have city name at the end e.g. `college of new calendonia`

**I want to remove the City names** from the data that have City name at the end of the column `school`

I tried to write the following SQL Statements by referring to some of the previously asked questions:

```
select school from table_name where school REGEXP '\-\\s\-\\s.*$';

select school from table_name where school REGEXP '\-\s\-\s.*$';
```

Essentially, I am trying to find the schools ending with the pattern `- city_name -` and remove the `- city_name -`.

If I am able to select the above REGEX, I can use CASE when for removing if I mind a matching pattern.

Please note: I went through the Regex docs and could not find anything related.

Comment: Looks like `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(schoolname, ' - ', 1) AS schoolname FROM sourcetable;`.

Comment: Don't limit yourself with just `REGEX` function. The most important thing is to identify the data pattern. If all of the city start only after the dash/hyphen (`-`), then Akina's suggested `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` should be able to get what you want. If there are other conditions in the data probably some data like this exists `Janus Academy - Junior -Calgary`, whereby there are two dashes and the city only appears after the second dash, then that need additional operation.

Comment: @FanoFN I agree to your point. I could have used SUBSTRING_INDEX if all the school name had the exact pattern. i.e. ` - city`. But many of the schools might have ` - ` in the school name as well. e.g. `Associated Hebrew Schools of Toronto - Central Administration - North York`. I want to remove `North York`, not `Central Administration - North York`

Comment: Maybe `SELECT LEFT(school, CHAR_LENGTH(school) - LOCATE(" - ", REVERSE(school))-2) As RESULT FROM table_name;`? See [this demo online](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cUnXEK2MfuNva6wvGQDLfB/0).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: almost, see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cUnXEK2MfuNva6wvGQDLfB/0 where is strips the last 2 characters of "college of new calendonia"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE 
   WHEN INSTR(school, " - ") > 0 THEN 
     LEFT(school, CHAR_LENGTH(school) - LOCATE(" - ", REVERSE(school))-2)
   ELSE
     school
   END
As RESULT FROM table_name;
```

See the [online demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a2CnKQkQDBH2rueE23h6u6/2).

Testing against

```sql
create table table_name (school varchar(320), ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into table_name (school) values ("Associated Hebrew Schools of Toronto - Central Administration - North York");
insert into table_name (school) values ("Associated Hebrew Schools of Toronto");
```

yields

[image]

Also, if you are using MySQL v.8+, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
create table table_name (school varchar(320), ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into table_name (school) values ("Associated Hebrew Schools of Toronto - Central Administration - North York");
insert into table_name (school) values ("Associated Hebrew Schools of Toronto - North York");
insert into table_name (school) values ("Associated Hebrew Schools of Toronto");

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(school, "(.*)\\s-\\s.*", "$1") As RESULT FROM table_name;
```

Here, `(.*)\s-\s.*` matches and captures into Group 1 any text up to [whitespace]-[whitespace], then the latter is matched and the `.*` matches and consumes the rest of the string; the `$1` replacement puts back the Group 1 value. See [this online DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cUnXEK2MfuNva6wvGQDLfB/1) yielding

[image]